# Why is the value returned by val() in my code empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui

I tried to change the UI for an open dialog box from displaying the list of files to open from inside a select box to a table with 2 columns.

original code:

JSP

```
<select size="15" id="options" class="dialog-pane-right"></select>
```

javascript

```
for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        var page = data[index];   //data: data to be listed inside select box
        var id = page.id || page;
        var title = page.title || id;

        var $option = $("<option></option>");
        $option.html(title);
        $option.attr("value", id);
}
```

alerting the choice when clicked on it

```
choice = $('select#options option');
choice.click(function(){
    alert($(this).val);
});
```

now I changed the select box to a table like this:

JSP

```
<table id="load-opt"></table>
```

javascript

```
for(var ind=0; ind<data.length; ind++) {
    //name is the name and desc is the description for each option
    var $option = $("<tr></tr>");
    $option.html("<td>"+name+"</td><td>"+desc+"</td>");
    $option.attr("value", id);
}
```

alerting the choice when clicked on it

```
var choice = $('table#load-opt tr td');
choice.click(function(){
    alert($(this.val()); 
});
```

the former alerts the name of the file I clicked on, but the latter gives an empty alert box. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: only `input` and `textarea` has value property, try use `$(this).text()` or `$(this).html()` instead.

Comment: You need to find `innerText` or `text()` not `val()` as it is not form element!

Comment: @fuyushimoya : I know that text() works, but I want to know why val() is failing. And it's working on select option.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery's `val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is used to get or set the `value` property of one or more elements.

In your case, it happens because the [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) (`<option>`) has a `value` property, and the [HTMLTableCellElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) (`<td>`) doesn't have one. You should use `.text()` instead of `.val()`, e.g:

```
var choice = $('table#load-opt tr td');
choice.click(function(){
    alert($(this.text()); 
});
```